# scrollable tab bar widget solution

Tags: javascript, html, tabcontrol, widget

I have a web page that I use to update a fairly complex data structure.

The page itself has lots of information, so I developed some simple Tab-page control, with plain html.

Each tab is a different page, so when the user click on a tab a post is issued to the new page.

Fairly simply.

The problem is that the page has about 10 tabs, so it no longer fits on screens.

I'd like to know if you can advice some way to develop a scrollable tab bar or any other way to overcome this situation. maybe a widget or something...

thanks a lot

saludos

sas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found this

```
<div style="overflow:auto; width:100%">
<table border="1" >
  <tr>
    <td>10000000000000000000000000000000000</td>
    <td>10000000000000000000000000000000000</td>
    <td>10000000000000000000000000000000000</td>
    <td>10000000000000000000000000000000000</td>
    <td>10000000000000000000000000000000000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

it seems like it could work...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to rethink your design a bit. When you run into problems where your chosen design won't scale to your requirements (in your case, enough tabs to organize lots of data), it's a good idea to revisit your initial design ideas. Without more information, I can't say much for your specific case, but other design concepts might help: master-detail views, wizards, and more information hierarchy might help reduce the number of tabs you need.